# TextBox ConvertBack event doesn't fire for XML element

Tags: wpf

`ValueFormattingConverter.Convert` is called with the `XmlElement`.  `ConvertBack` is never called.  Why?  Is there some obligation to pass binding directives down the chain?  Is the use of the TextBox overriding its own binding settings?  What can be done?

My TextBox

```
<TextBox Width="200" 
         Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource valueFormattingConverter}}",
         Mode=TwoWay,
         NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,
         NotifyOnValidationError=True,                
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Usage is rather convoluted.  Starting at the top, we provide an XML element to a tab.

```
<TabItem.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource mcf}", 
             XPath="mdf/press_information"/>
</TabItem.DataContext>
```

That tab contains a `ItemsControl` which builds `TextBox`es through this `ControlChooser` which passes the binding along.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <W3V:ControlChooser RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=W3V:ObjectList}", 
                            Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

My converter class header.  Convert method is called.  ConvertBack never.

```
  [ValueConversion(typeof(XmlElement), typeof(string))]
  public class ValueFormattingConverter : IValueConverter
```

EDIT: The chosen answer basically says Path=. doesn't support 2-way binding.  I believe it is the correct answer to the question.  Very helpful to know, but "can't do that" doesn't solve the larger problem.  So I have laid out the larger question here: [Means of generating an editable form from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091405/means-of-generating-an-editable-form-from-xml).

Comment: Are you converting the value back to the source in a two-way binding? Binding has to be two way for `ConvertBack` to work.

Comment: Oops edited TextBox, but problem is still a problem.

Comment: When you type stuff in the `TextBox`, what exactly happens?

Comment: It gets in the box, but ConvertBack doesn't get called.

Comment: Is the source actually getting updated though? Text changed in the box might not necessarily mean the source is actually updated. Maybe add this to your textbox: `NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"`, type something in and catch the source update (maybe wherever the setter is).

Comment: This is the point.  The source cannot possibly be updated without calling the ConvertBack method.  Still I inserted your line to see if anything can be observed, but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The binding direction *to source* won't work with a `{Binding Path=.}`. This is because there is no bound property, but just the binding source object.

Hence there will never be a source update, and the `ConvertBack` method is never called, because that would mean to replace the source object.

In order to make your code work, you would have to bind to some property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeElement, ...}"/>
```

Comment: This may be useful, but I'm not clear how to get there.  The object I'm receiving is an XmlElement, and I want that element object because the conversion involves multiple attributes.  What object might I receive instead that I could use your line of code to access my XmlElement?

Comment: Or, I could use XPath=@value, IF there were also a way to access the other properties.  value is what changes, while the others affect how to format value.

Comment: I think this is your answer. +1.  Use Snoop to figure out your bound objects and such.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much more to say here. Binding directly to an object (as opposed to binding to one of its properties) is inherently one-way. You may probably create a suitable view model, but how this could look like can't be told from what you've shown in your question.

Comment: I think perhaps a MultiBinding is the way to go.  I think your answer is correct, it's just not complete in that I can't use it as is.

Comment: The answer can't be complete in a way that it "solves your problem". You haven't provided enough information to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Turns out Multibinding also doesn't help.  These controls are generated by a datatemplate instantiated across XmlElements.  So I have an XmlElement, an '@value' property formatted according to an '@format' attribute.  but I have no way that I can see of getting back to that XmlElement.  I can't set '@value' without '@format'.

Comment: Backing away from the details of the code above, I need a solution to edit a series of values from XML.  Maybe that needs to be a new question.