# WPF Textbox TwoWay binding in datatemplate not updating the source

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, datatemplate

I created a ListBox in which I specified a DataTemplate with a Grid and two elements in it (TextBlock and TextBox). The source in ListBox is ObservableCollection<int>. Everything displays fine, but when I try to change the value in the TextBox, the binding source does not change.

I followed this solution to solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110958/20863772

But it didn't work. TextBoxes now display nothing (even though the collection is populated correctly and has elements)

Here is the View code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlugboardPermutations, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         BorderThickness="0"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         xmlns:system='clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib'
         AlternationCount="{x:Static system:Int32.MaxValue}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding ListSelectedIndex}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
    
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="30" TextAlignment="Right" 
                           Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                      StringFormat=' {0}: ', Mode=OneWay}"/>

                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Width="30" DataContext="{Binding Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Tag="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `Path=Content` when the ItemsSource is a collection of `int`s? Be aware that a TwoWay Binding can not replace an element in the source collection.

Comment: Also note that UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings and only if the target object actually changes the target property.

Comment: @Clemens, `Path=Content` this is from the solution that I added as already tried.

Comment: There is no Content property in your view model. The Binding makes no sense. Replace your `ObservableCollection<int>` with an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` where MyItem has a property that you can bind to.